# VBA word doc - Show different items based on selection

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm trying to reduce the size of a form, so I want to hide and show sections based on input.

- It's not efficient to program in all of the items I need to show,
  I've already written more than 100 lines for one page and there are
  eighteen pages total. The pages contain a mix of Tables, images,
  paragraphs, and ActiveX object (textbox, combobox, etc)
  .
- I was looking around and there was a hidden method that existed for
  tables previously. But I tried it and found out that it doesn't work
  for Word-2010. Are there any replacements for this?

My thoughts

- Right now the only thing I can think of is putting unique IDs all over the file, when I need to replace one with a table I can search for the UID and get its range then insert the table there. CONS: Believe me, it'll take a week at best. This also doesn't deal with images and leaves annoying UID's in plain sight of the user. I think Any other solution is better than this.
- I'm hoping there is an object I can put everything in, then hide it.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Build a web application ;-D

Comment: Can you build a web app without a server (browser app)? I was searching and found browser apps but I'm having trouble figuring out how its done. How would the user launch a browser app? Is it just an html file?

Comment: I actually don't have any experience with it myself, but you can do it (this is an example article: http://www.htmlgoodies.com/html5/other/build-an-offline-html5-web-application.html#fbid=WgkzQnFvFes). I do know that, although my comment above was a joke, I seriously would look at what you are doing and see if there is a better approach. It all depends on your environment though.

Comment: Have you considered using multiple forms to accomplish this? Create a template that gets copied and modified to give the illusion of a single form reacting to events? The trick is keeping track of the window's position...

Comment: That's the UID's marking positions, and they are a mess

Comment: Done. Josh, make the web app an answer and I'll accept it. Just making an HTML file and launching it in the browser worked (can even give references to all the images by keeping them on the local network).